# Is it possible to access Sharepoint Online lists using the Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to access a sharepoint list from iOS (using Swift).  Is this possible using the Microsoft Graph API?  If so, how?  If not, how should it be done?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Graph API currently doesn’t include SharePoint lists.
Another choice is that you could use ADALiOS library which could make native ios applications that connect to Office 365 and SharePoint Online. The library framework will automatically cache the user’s access and refresh tokens for use on subsequent authorization or cache access calls. Over HTTPS, the client application uses the returned JWT access token to add the JWT string with a “Bearer” designation in the Authorization header of the request to the web API. The web API then validates the JWT token, and if validation is successful, returns the desired resource.You could take advantage of SharePoint REST API calls as long as the correct permissions added to the native application in Azure to get the sharepoint lists:

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest =
  (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
  "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists");
endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", 
  "Bearer " + accessToken);
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse =
  (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try and report back how it goes.

Comment: I've just started testing this out.  I've added the ADALiOS library with a podfile and successfully got a token.  However, it's giving a ton of warnings -- looks like they haven't updated it for iOS 9?  Is this library going to be around for a while -- I don't want to create a production app on this if not.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Graph API exposes documents in OneDrive and Groups, other SharePoint sites and document libraries are not exposed yet, we will enable that scenario in the future.